# how install ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, 15.10

I want to use ubuntu. but I dont know how I can Install it. I am A new in this os. So can tell me please how I can install ubuntu 15.10 on my Laptop Lenovo Flex10 with Windows 10 as second System? 
Thank you
Sincerely
EldarAzal

Answer (score 0):

If you were just asking your question to google you will have million of answers and all you have to do is to pick up one.

For your convenience here the official ubuntu guide for beginners:

```
 http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop
```